# How to connect android app to PrestaShop?

Tags: android, json, parsing, xml-parsing, prestashop-1.6

i already looked at most of the questions related to prestashop.Some of them is saying that there is no api for prestashop.look at this link

http://online.fastchef.in/api/customers/12?output_format=JSON

it is giving result in json form.only thing is to parse this form.but still m getting error
My Code:MainActivity

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)     
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
 int id=Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());


 PrestaShopClient client =retrofit.create(PrestaShopClient.class);
 Call<Customer> hj=client.getCustomer(id);
 hj.enqueue(new Callback<Customer>() {

      @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<Customer> call, Response<Customer> response) {

              int status = response.code();
              Customer customer = response.body();
              mTextView.setText(customer.getFirstname());
                                                           }

     @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Customer> call, Throwable t) {

                                                         }
                          });
```

PrestaShopCLient:

```
public interface PrestaShopClient {

@GET("customers/{id}?output_format=JSON")
Call<Customer> getCustomer(@Path("id") int id);
```

}

help me out guys...this problem took my day nd half ;(

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you to create a separate web service that will communicate with your android app and fetches and passes data in JSON format.

Web service means a PHP file that is present inside your PrestaShop installation. It performs operations on the basis of received requests and returns the data in JSON format that can be further decoded by your android app for respective functionalities.

You can download a web service from the following link

[Prestashop Android App](https://www.knowband.com/prestashop-android-mobile-app-builder-free?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=prestashop&utm_term=prestashop-mobile-app&utm_campaign=participation)

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, this is advertising of your own paid product